# HttpResponse não retornando nada

Tags: python

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Seguinte, estou com problema com essa mensagem.. o que pode ser?

Segue o meu código!! Estou tentando acesso a "pagina" e surge essa mensagem..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo, primeiro edite sua pergunta colando o código, não o print. Da forma que está a pergunta dificilmente conseguiremos ajudar

Comment: Obrigado! Estou sem o código fonte no momento, pois não estou no meu computador particular. Assim que possível, atualizo o post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A imagem não mostra o código todo, mas parece que a sua view está retornando None.

Você marcou uma linha do código, mas essa não é a única linha que retorna alguma coisa nesse método. Na verdade tem um if:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Se isso for falso, não vai nem entrar nessa parte do código que você postou. Lembre-se que se a função não executar nenhum `return` o python automaticamente retorna `None` o que pode estar causando seu erro.

Answer (score 0):

É porque o Python pega o bloco pela indentação.

Observe que seu `return render` está "na mesma linha vertical" que o `if request.method == 'POST'`.

Isso vai fazer com que seu método `add_user` só retorne o `render` ou `HttpResponse` caso o método seja `POST`

Além disso há um outro trecho que parece ser um erro, que é o do `else`. Parece-me que a intenção era deixar o `form = UserForm()` vazio apenas caso não fosse uma requisição POST.

a correção mais aproximada no seu caso é o seguinte código:

```
def add_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Usuário criado com sucesso")
    else:
        form = UserForm()


    return render(request, 'accounts/add_user.html', {'form' : form})
```

No caso da sua validação se o formulário é válido, não faz sentido não ter um `else`, então eu adicionaria mais um:

```
def add_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Usuário criado com sucesso")
        else:
            # Redirecione ou mostre uma mensagem de erro aqui
    else:
        form = UserForm()


    return render(request, 'accounts/add_user.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: Poderiam deixar um feedback a respeito do negativo? O que há de errado como a resposta?

Comment: Realizei uma nova interação, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @duardoalmeida se for uma nova informação, você pode fazer uma nova pergunta no site

Comment: é referente a mesma pergunta, pois ainda não consegui resolver o problema.. a interação que fiz foi neste post

Comment: Qual nova interação?